# Why can't Guice bind for an intermediate dependency?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Here's my code:

```
// Groovy
interface MyMapper {
    Buzz toBuzz(Fizz fizz);
}

class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {
    @Named("SIMPLE_FOOBAR")
    Foobar foobar;

    MyMapperImpl(Foobar foobar) {
        super();
        this.foobar = foobar;
    }

    @Override
    Buzz toBuzz(Fizz fizz) {
        // ...etc.
    }
}

class Whistlefeather {
    MyMapper mapper;

    Whistlefeather(MyMapper mapper) {
        super();

        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    void doSomething(Fink fink) {
        Fizz fizz = getSomehow(fink);
        Buzz buzz = mapper.toBuzz(fizz);

        // Do something with 'buzz'...
    }
}

class ApplicationMain {
    Whistlefeather whistlefeather;

    @Inject
    ApplicationMain(Whistlefeather whistlefeather) {
        super();

        this.whistlefeather = whistlefeather;
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule());
        ApplicationMain appMain = injector.getInstance(ApplicationMain);
        appMain.run();
    }

    void run() {
        whistlefeather.doSomething(new Fink());
    }
}
```

Here's my Guice module:

```
class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // I have to name the Foobars because in reality there will be
        // *many* of them, each configured slightly different.
        bind(Foobar.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("SIMPLE_FOOBAR"))
            .toInstance(new Foobar(true, true, false, 103, "yee haw"));

        bind(MyMapper.class).to(MyMapperImpl);
    }
}
```

Here's my exception:

```
Could not find a suitable constructor in com.me.myapp.MyMapperImpl.
Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated
with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
```

My *understanding* was that I only need to annotate constructors with `@Inject` if I would be directly calling them through the `Injector#getInstance(...)` method. Since I do this with `ApplicationMain`, which contains a reference to `Whistlefeather`, which contains a reference to `MyMapper`, I didn't think I would have to annotate the `MyMapperImpl` constructor.

Any ideas as to where I'm going awry here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for Guice to create *any* object, it has to know which constructor to use. This is true all the way down the [Object Graph](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted).

Consider the following code:

```
public interface Something { }
```

```
public class SomethingImpl implements Something {
  private final String data;

  public SomethingImpl(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public SomethingImpl(Integer data) {
    this.data = data.toString();
  }
}
```

```
public class AnotherClass {
  private final Something something;

  @Inject
  public AnotherClass(Something something) {
    this.something = something;
  }
}
```

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() { 
    bind(Something.class).to(SomethingImpl.class);
    bind(String.class).toInstance("Hello!");
    bind(Integer.class).toInstance(50);
  }
}
```

In this scenario, how is Guice supposed to know which constructor to use in `SomethingImpl`? *If you were the author of Guice, how would you write it?*

Obviously, **you can't** answer, because it's impossible. There has to be some sort of mechanism to tell Guice which constructor to use, regardless of whether or not it's called by `Injector.getInstance()` or not; that's why you have to annotate at least one constructor. Guice will use a no-argument constructor by default if one is specified, but if there isn't one, Guice doesn't know what to do.